# How to set the type on enum in swift?

Tags: swift

I am attempting to create a property on a struct that accepts a size param (small, med, large) where each size enumerates a CGFloat value to be used in a modifier.

```
Struct CoolView: View {

enum Size: CGFloat {    
        case large = 100
        case medium = 200
        case small = 400
    }

let size: Size = .small

  var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Color.green
                .cornerRadius(size)
```

I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'CoolView.Size' to expected argument type 'CGFloat?' yet I am setting `enum Size: CGFloat`

Comment: try to look for the enum documentation, ```size.rawValue```` should answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the `rawValue` of the enum case:

`.cornerRadius(size.rawValue)`